# Tools like Xming in linux

Tags: linux, vps, xming

Are there tools like Xming in Linux to show my plot on VPS?

The effect is like this:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzCLPN5o3ziHUHNmc2ZFSTRLM0k

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzCLPN5o3ziHUjhqSWFVVGhDdnc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely don't need to install any additional software, as most Linux desktop distributions have X11 installed by default. Just run the `ssh` command with the `-X` flag enabled.